# Why does this Haskell statement not evaluate lazily?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci

I have the following function defined:

```
ex 1 x = 1
ex 0 x = 0
ex b x = b ** x
```

Then, when I execute the following:

```
1 `ex` (sum [1..])
```

it tries to calculate the sum of the infinite sequence, instead of being lazy and returning 1.  Why?

---

EDIT: Upon further investigation, I found that laziness happens if I define the `ex` function in a file, but not if I define it in GHCI:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 6.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> let ex 1 x = 1
Prelude> let ex b x = b ** x
Prelude> ex 1 (sum [1..])
<interactive>: out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)
```

If I pull the `ex` definition into a file (in this case, test.hs):

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 6.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :load test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> ex 1 (sum [1..])
1.0
```

The new question, then, is why?

Comment: No, 1 `ex` (sum [1..]) does return 1.0 on my computer. What version of ghc etc.? And do you get the same result with ex 1 (sum [1..])?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Good points, see my update above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In GHCi, each `let` statement introduces a *new* definition of `ex`, instead of multiple pattern cases as you expect. So it hangs because, when you enter `ex 1 (sum [1..])` afterwards, only the final `ex b x = b ** x` version exists.

If you want to define a function with multiple pattern cases in GHCi, you'll need to put it in a single `let` statement, like this:

```
let ex 1 x = 1; ex 0 x = 0; ex b x = b ** x
```

The same applies for anything else that would normally be written across multiple lines, such as `do` notation. For instance, a function like this:

```
f x = do
    y <- get
    put (x + y)
    return y
```

Would have to be written like this in GHCi:

```
let f x = do { y <- get; put (x + y); return y }
```

Comment: Aha, that's really inconvenient. Good to know, though, thanks!

Comment: @perimosocordiae: As a fairly heavy user of GHCi, I've generally taken up the habit of writing most or all of my definitions in an external file, loading the file with GHCi, and using the REPL mostly for evaluating simple expressions.

Comment: You can also use `:set +m` to write definitions over multiple lines.

Comment: @aleator: A feature which is newer than this post, I believe. I shudder to think how many of my answers are now silly in light of newer GHC features and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude> let ex 1 x = 1
Prelude> let ex b x = b ** x
```

You're not defining a function with two cases here. You define a function with one case, and then you define it again overriding the previous definition.

To define one function with two patterns use `let ex 1 x = 1; ex b x = b ** x`, i.e. separate the cases with a semicolon.

Answer (score -2):

I missed one point of laziness, which renders the answer below false.

---

Because `sum` calculates the total sum of all elements in the sequence. Which is, in your case, endless.

You probably want

```
map ((curry ex) 1) [1..]
```

That is

```
map -- map each item x to y
    (
        (
            curry ex -- curry ex, to transform (x, y) -> z into x -> y -> z
        )
        1 -- then invoke it with 1, which results in y -> z, x being 1
    )
    [1..] -- the infinite sequence to be mapped.
```

Comment: -1: It would only evaluate the sum if it was actually needed, and in this case it wasn't.